# TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' when dealing with images

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, python-imaging-library, data-science

I'm trying to split data to train/test/val sets, but I get this error:

```
   for filename in os.listdir("Data/Descriptions"):
        image = Image.open("Data/Images/" + filename + ".jpeg")
        image = image.resize((new_width, new_height), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
        images.append(np.array(image))
        #images.append(np.asarray(image))

   train_images= images[:int(len(images * 0.8))]
   labels = transfomed_labels[:int(len(transfomed_labels * 0.8))]
```

> TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Anyone knows the solution?

Comment: using `len( images * 0.8 )` you try to multiply every image by 0.8. You need rather  `len(images) * 0.8` to multiply size of data.

Comment: Also, you may want to post the line numbers for any errors, if you have them. They're very valuable for narrowing down to the issue.

Comment: A word of warning with doing mathematical operations on images. A typical image has three channels for color (R, G, B) and can take values 0 to 255. If you go below zero or above 255, numpy will roll the data over ( 256 --> 0, and -1 --> 255). To avoid this, you can use a data type with more bits, clip over/underflow to 0 to 255 with np.clip(), and recast data to np.uint8. If you use the OpenCV library, you can find functions that do the clipping for you automatically. In this specific example, you are multipliying by 0.8, so it is not an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for me you have `)` in wrong place

Using

```
len( images * 0.8 )
```

you try to multiply every image by 0.8.

You need rather

```
len(images) * 0.8
```

to multiply size of data.